# combinatorics - number of ways to choose r out of n (with inclusion-exclusion)

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Quick question.

Out of a set of $n$ apples, we are given that $m$ are delicious. Show that the number of different combinations to choose $r$ apples that contain all of the delicious ones is given by this formula:

$$\binom{n-m}{r-m}=\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^k\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-k}{r}, 0\leq m \leq r \leq n$$

I did not manage to solve this question, but I think the best way (and the way the teacher intended) is to use inclusion exclusion and find what $\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^k\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-k}{r}$ represents.

Could anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to understand the way it is on the left hand side. You want to choose $r$ apples. You know you have to choose the $m$ delicious ones. So now you have to choose $r-m$ more our of the $n-m$ remaining apples. Hence there are $\binom{n-m}{r-m}$ such choices.

I'm not sure how to express it as in the right hand side; I'll be interested to find out.

Comment: Yes, that is obvious, but we still need to show why that is equal to the right hand side.